# Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL... Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-3

I am trying to log in with facebook application using codeigniter php. I am getting error:

> Warning
>       Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I have done some research and I think my Valid OAuth Redirect URIs in Facebook application is wrong/invalid. 
Can someone guide me how to solve this issue?

Here is the image of my link

[image: Here is the image of my link]

Comment: You need to add your domain URL in your facebook app settings...

Comment: This helped me: https://wp-native-articles.com/blog/news/how-to-fix-facebook-apps-error-cant-load-url-domain-url-isnt-included-apps-domains/

Answer (score 4):

It was confirmed on Facebook’s bug platform that they had made some changes to the the default settings for new Apps and now Strict Mode is automatically enabled for the oAuth settings.Strict mode means that when using Facebook login to connect your application or website to the App, the oAuth redirect URL has to be explicitly set, where as before it didn’t.

**So, here is the step to fix it:**

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and select the app you
   wish to fix.
2. At the bottom of the left hand menu click **+ Add Product** link.
3. Select Facebook Login as the Product.
4. Select Web.
5. Enter your **Site URL** and hit **save**.
6. Hit Continue then keep clicking Next, ignoring all the code, until
   you get to Step 5. ​
7. In the left hand menu you should now see Facebook Login, click the
   Settings menu item underneath it. ​
8. Under Client oAuth settings, where it says **Use Strict Mode for
   Redirect URIs** make sure it’s set to **No** and that your site URL is in
   the Valid OAuth redirect URIs box. Then the hit **save**.
9. ​You should now be able to connect your app as normal.

Hope it will fix your problem.